# No implicit reference conversion (interface abstractions)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I found myself not following the DRY principle when I saw some copy pasted code. Pretty much

3x interfaces 
3x classes

where the classes and interfaces where exactly the same.
Fine, remove the 2x interfaces and let the interface origin be only one as they are the same.

1x interface
3x classes

But since the classes did the exact same thing, I want to trim it down to

1x interface
1x classes

So the interface and class pretty much looks like

```cs
public class Foo : IFoo { }
```

Now that I want to register 3x difference instances of `Foo` as a singleton but with difference configurations, I get a compilation error. So my initial though was to have some marker interface for that, let's call them `IBar , IBaz  and IQux` where all inherit from `IFoo` like:

```cs
public interface IBar : IFoo { }

public interface IBaz : IFoo { }

public interface IQux : IFoo { }
```

And register like:

```cs
services
    .AddSingleton<IBar, Foo>(sp => /* configuration */)
    .AddSingleton<IBaz, Foo>(sp => /* configuration */)
    .AddSingleton<IQux, Foo>(sp => /* configuration */);
```

The compilation error I'm getting:

> There is not implicit reference conversion from `Foo` to `IBar`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `Foo` does not implement `IBar`. Simple.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama yeap you're right, must have brain farted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your marker interfaces inherit from `IFoo` and your class inherits from `IFoo`. Which means these four are just different implementations of `IFoo`. And you are trying to use `Foo` class as an implementation of `IBar, IBaz, IQux` which is not the case here.

Your `Foo` class should inherit from marker interfaces like so

```
public class Foo : IBar, IBaz, IQux { }
```

and then the following code should now work

```
services
    .AddSingleton<IBar, Foo>(sp => /* configuration */)
    .AddSingleton<IBaz, Foo>(sp => /* configuration */)
    .AddSingleton<IQux, Foo>(sp => /* configuration */);
```